Spring Boot and Angular: 403 Response for Preflight
I have a problem with the communication between my Angular application and a Spring Boot microservice. I receive a 403 response when sending a preflight request. I thought I had properly configured the microservice with a security filter chain. But see for yourselves.
The SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), CorsFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .build();
}

Here are my CORS Configs:
    @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    return new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource());
}

I thought that Cors configured correctly and when im accessing the APIs with Postman and a valid Bearer it works fine. However, when im trying to access it from the Angular Application im getting the following error:

The CORS error, as I understand it, results from the failed preflight request, which should actually have all the CORS options. If you could help me out, it would be very nice. If you need any more information, please let me know. Thank you in advance and best regards.

not sure if this is the issue, but be aware that when sending credentials you cannot wildcard origins.  List them explicitly.  Also make sure the requests are HTTPS
